# Android - Volley : Response is too late

Tags: android, android-volley

So I've run into a problem in my code, where I need to get a JSONString from my server with volley. And then I have to parse the String into a JSONObject and then continue doing stuff with that.

My problem here is, that Volley gives the response too late, meaning my string that I want to parse is always empty because its not initialised yet.

```
RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, searchURLBuilder, future, future);
//        new Response.Listener<String>() {
//            @Override
//            public void onResponse(String response) {
//                writeToSharedResponse(response_for_search, response);
//            }
//        },
//        new Response.ErrorListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
//                 Log.d("Error!!:" + error.getMessage(), "");
//            }
//        });
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
String response = "";
try {
    response = future.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String responseString = m.getString(response_for_search, new String());

pieceDTOList = getPiecesDTOFromJSON(responseString);
```

Here is a snippet of my code. As you can see I already tried to make a "future" call to block and wait for the answer, but it just times out every time. The commented out bit, is the part I actually wanted to use from the beginning, but that returns the response to late. Since its asynchronous and accesses the server w/e it wants.

writeToSharedResponse just writes the answer into a sharedPreferences variable.

```
private SharedPreferences m;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

private RequestQueue requestQueue;

public DbParser(Context c) {
    m = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
    editor = m.edit();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(c);
}
```

My Question here is: Is there an easy way I can "wait" for the answer from volley so I can continue to work with the response that I get?

Edit 1:

I now added an interface and changed the code around to this:

```
    getString(new VolleyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            getPiecesDTOFromJSON(result);
        }
    }, searchURLBuilder);


    return globalPieceDTOList;

}

private void getString(final VolleyCallback callback, String searchUrl){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, searchUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    callback.onSuccess(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Error!!:" + error.getMessage(), "");
                }
            });
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Since I cant get the values out of my inner classes, I did a nasty hack and created a global list for my DTO's. The problem now is that "return globalPieceDTOList" is always Null. And again - I would need to "wait" for the Volley response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volley requests are async, so when you try to return a value, the request is likely not done yet. If you want to return values from a Volley request use callback interfaces.

Example

```
public void getString(final VolleyCallback callback) {
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            // do some things here
            callback.onSuccess(<PASS STRING RESULT HERE>);
        }
    });
}

public interface VolleyCallback{
    void onSuccess(String result);
}
```

Example usage:

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    getString(new VolleyCallback(){
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(String result){
             //do stuff here with the result from the volley request
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: Would you be so kind and look at my Edit 1? I still got problems with your solution.

Comment: Post the complete code of where you call `getString()`

Comment: Im not doing anything fancy before calling getString() just building the searchURLBuilder String - which is a php site that I want to access.

Comment: You call `getString()` from a method, and you want that method to return `globalPieceDTOList`. I don't know what `globalPieceDTOList` is or what `getPiecesDTOFromJSON` does and where you use the method. So all I can say is move the rest of your code inside the `onSuccess` so you can handle everything from there.

Comment: eeeyyy - I just made it work. Thanks for your answer!